Determine whether $ \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\ln x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\ln x}dx $ diverges or converges.
I'm going through my learning material, and one of following question at the end of it was:

Determine whether the integral $ \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\ln x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\ln x}dx $ diverges, converges or absolutely converges.

The chapter I was going over focused on functions whose anti-derivative may be hard to find. Specifically on whether their integral, in some range (potentially infinity), diverges or converges. Prior to this question there were 2 main ways:

The limit comparison test on two functions $ f(x),g(x) $ such that both are always positive.
Dirichlet's test.

Another way, was to show that an integral is equal to a sum of two other integrals. If one diverges and the other converges, conclude the original also diverges. Or if both converge, conclude the original converges.
I was able to solve all other question using one of methods listed above, however this one completely stumped me.
$ \frac{\cos\left(\ln x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\ln x} $ clearly isn't always positive, so I can't use the comparison test. I could try checking if it is absolutely convergent. In case it is, I would deduce it converges.
(maybe something in the likes of this?): Examine: $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos(\ln x)|}{x\ln(x)}dx$. Using $u$ subsitution for $u=\ln x \rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x}dx$:
$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos(\ln x)|}{x\ln(x)}dx = \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos(\ln x)|}{\ln(x)}\frac{1}{x} dx = \int_{\ln2}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos(u)|}{u}du = \int_{\ln2}^{\infty}|\frac{\cos(u)}{u}|du $
Using a previous question in the book I showed that the above diverges. But the above is only similar to the one in question, and it's clear that for any $x>2$: $\frac{|cos(\ln x)|}{(x+1)\ln x} < \frac{|cos(\ln x)|}{x\ln x}$ hence the limit comparison test doesn't help...
Next, $ \int_{2}^{\infty} \cos (\ln x) dx$ clearly doesn't converge, and $\cos (\ln x) $ isn't monotonic either, which means I can't use Dirichlet's test.
The only last idea I've had was to try integrating by parts $ \frac{\cos\left(\ln x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\ln x} $, but no matter which functions $v,u$ I chose, the result didn't seem very helpful.
I also tried to search whether somebody already asked this question (or anything similar) here, or on other sites, but to no avail.
Thanks in advance!

Letting $u=\ln(x)$ we have $dx=e^udu$ and thus the integral transforms into $$\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty \frac{\cos(u)e^u}{(e^{u}+1)u}du=\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty \frac{\cos(u)}{u}du-\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty \frac{\cos(u)}{(e^{u}+1)u}du$$
The first integral is just an offset of a very famous integral, the convergence of which is shown, for instance, here.
The second integral absolutely converges, as $$\left|\frac{\cos(u)}{(e^{u}+1)u}\right|\leq\frac{1}{u^2}$$
and $$\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty \dfrac{1}{u^2}du=\dfrac{1}{\ln(2)}<\infty$$
Being the difference of two convergent integrals, we conclude $$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\ln x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\ln x}dx$$
converges too.

Fantastic! Thanks :)
